# HtmlParser vs BrowsingContext

Tags: .net, anglesharp

Which one would be more efficient? The docs don't seem to explain these I believe:

```
    private static async Task<AngleSharp.Dom.IDocument> S(Stream source)
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default;
        //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

        //Create a virtual request to specify the document to load (here from our fixed string)
        return await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(source));
    }

    private static async Task<AngleSharp.Html.Dom.IHtmlDocument> F(Stream source)
    {
        var a = new HtmlParser();
        var b = await a.ParseDocumentAsync(source);
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. The `HtmlParser` still creates a `BrowsingContext` if none has been given.

Recommendation is to always use the `BrowsingContext`. This way, you see what you use (and you have additional options / flexibility) when doing so.